# Using :selected binding on select with bound value

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I want to select a  tag depending on it's value, which is nothing all too special and I got it working when using directly.

```
<select id="some-select" @input="doSomething($event.target.value)">
  <option value="example" :selected="dependency === 'example'">A Name</option>
  <option value="anotherOne" :selected="dependency === 'anotherOne'">Another Name</option>
</select>
```

Now I wanted to refactor my Code and create a few reusable components for basic inputs. So I created a custom-select. Here comes the problem:
I need the input/select to work with v-model. and therefore I have a `:value="modelValue"` binding on the `select`. This is overwriting the selected status even if it matches and selected would be true.

The question is: How could I work around the :selected binding and set the `modelValue` initially to be the matching `option`

Since modelValue is (and has to be) a prop, I can't write it directly from within the component.

```
<custom-select :selection-set="availableOptions" :is-seamless="true" :selected-value="dependency"
      @input="doSomething($event.target.value)"/>
```

Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <select :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" :id="displayName" :class="classObject" :style="styleObject">
      <option v-for="(option, index) in selectionSet" :key="index" :value="option.value" :selected="option.value === selectedValue">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'custom-select',
  props: {
    // ... various others, not important for given problem
    selectionSet: {
      type: Array, // The Array struct looks like: [{name: 'xy', value: 'xy'}, ...]
      required: true,
    },
    selectedValue: {
      type: String, // Is the same as dependency in the non component variation.
      required: false,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Documentation:

I solved the problem by passing an initial value for the `modelValue` prop on the `<custom-select>` call.

```
<custom-select :model-value="dependency" :selection-set="availableOptions" :is-seamless="true" :selected-value="dependency"
  @input="doSomething($event.target.value)"/>
```

and getting rid of the `:selected` binding within the component.